# How Java Picks an Overloaded Method in Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have two classes defined as:

```
public static class Mammal extends Animal {
    public void info(String s) {
        System.out.print("Mammal");
    }
}

public static class Animal {
    public void info(Object o) {
        System.out.print("Animal");
    }
}
```

Now I define two variables as:

```
Mammal m = new Mammal();
Animal a = new Mammal();
```

When I call `m.info("test")`, it will print

> "Mammal"

When I call `a.info("test")`, it will print

> "Animal"

Why does the `Mammal` type call the `Mammal` `info()` method and the `Animal` type call the `Animal` `info()` method when they are both `Mammal` objects?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're *overloading* the method, not *overriding* it.

Overloads are chosen at compile time, and when the compile-time type of `a` is `Animal`, then a call to `a.info("test")` can *only* resolve to the `info(Object)` method in `Animal`.

If you want to *override* the method, you need to use the same signature - specify the `@Override` annotation to get the compiler to check that for you:

```
public static class Mammal extends Animal {
    @Override public void info(Object s) {
        System.out.print("Mammal");
    }
}
```

Now it will print "Mammal" in both cases, because the *implementation* of the method is chosen at execution-time based on the actual type of the object. Remember the difference between them:

- Overloading: takes place at compile time, chooses the method signature
- Overriding: takes place at execution time, chooses the implementation of that signature

I also note that you're using nested classes (as otherwise the `static` modifier would be invalid). That doesn't change the behaviour here, but it does make other changes to the features of classes. I strongly suggest that you try to work with top-level classes most of the time, only using nested types when there's a *really* compelling reason to do so.

Comment: I understand I was overloading it, but I didn't realize the difference between overloading and overriding at compile/execution time. Your answer makes sense though.

Just to make sure I'm understanding this correctly: If I added a `info(String s, String s2)` method to the class `Mammal` but not to `Animal`, then `m.info("1", "2")` would work, but `a.info("1", "2")` wouldn't compile, right?

Comment: @user2471908: Correct.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
public void info(Object o) {
    System.out.print("Animal");
}
```

doesn't overrode

```
public void info(String s) {
    System.out.print("Mammal");
}
```

Their signatures are different. I.e one is `Object` the other - `String`.